# proving limit evaluates to infinity

Tags: limits

I have the following question..
\begin{align*}
f(n) &= n^{\sqrt{n}}\\
g(n) &= 2^{an},\quad \text{where $a > 1$}
\end{align*}
Evaluate the limit of $f(n)/g(n)$ as $n \to \infty$

I can intuitively see this has to be $0$, since $2^{an}$ grows much faster than $n^{\sqrt{n}}$, but how to show this rigorously?

Comment: Do you mean $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ instead of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?  Also, are you taking the limit as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion! I'll make the appropriate edits

Answer (score 1):

You may also apply the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) for infinite series and get

$$\displaystyle\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}} = 2^{-a}n^\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}2^{-a}\stackrel{a>1}{<}1\tag1$$

Since $a>1$ you have $2^{-a}<1$

Thus the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ converges, which implies, that

$$\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0 $$

---

To verify the  limit in (1) one can apply L'Hospital ($\star$) rule as follows

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \exp{\log \lim_{n\to\infty}n^\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=\exp{\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}}\stackrel{\star}{=} \exp \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n}}=\exp0=1$$

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ratio test for sequences. That is, evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^{\sqrt{n+1}}}{2^{a(n+1)}}*\frac{2^{an}}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}$$

and you should get $\frac{1}{2^a} <1$ (why?) implying that the sequence has a zero limit as $n$ tends to infinity.